# How to use OCR function for a custom language?

Tags: matlab, ocr, persian

Try using OCR function in Matlab for Persian language but doesn't work(nothing returned),
my codes are like this:

```
I=imread('111.jpg');
figure;
imshow(I);
roi=round(getPosition(imrect));
ocrResult=ocr(I,roi,'Language','path/to/tessdata/fas.traineddata');
ocrResult.Text
```

What should I do?

Use this simple picture for recognition:

[image: Use this simple picture for recognition:]

Comment: Is the path right? Does a really basic, clear example (e.g. small image containing only a single letter in black on white background) work?

Comment: Dear @nkjt, Thanks for your reply, yeah, everything is correct. It doesn't give me any error just an empty string. Have you tried this before?